# Maven multi-module project , Using binary dependencies for checking out particular modules from SVN

Tags: eclipse, maven

My multi module project has  this structure

```
+ Parent Project

    + Child Project A
            pom.xml
    + Child Project B
            pom.xml

    pom.xml
```

parent pom.xml has

```
<modules>
    <module>Child Project A</module>
    <module>Child Project B</module>
 </modules>
```

And in child project A and B pom.xml has

```
<parent>
        <groupId>Parent Project group Id</groupId>
        <artifactId>Parent Project artifact ID</artifactId>
        <version>Parent Project version</version>
 </parent>
```

And everything is added to SVN version control. If i check out the Parent Project from SVN all the sources are checked out into my eclipse.

Now if i want to check out Child project A alone which has dependency of Child Project B, but i donot want the source of Child Project B to be checked out ,  only binary of Child Project B should be added to the Child project A while Parent Project is checked out,  how to manage such dependencies in Maven Multi module Project.

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't like having checkedout the source of child B than you shouldn't create a multi-module out of it. Make separate projects with it's own pom and it's own locations in SVN (trunk/tags/branches).

Comment: I need all the sources to be kept inside one project and at one place so only have created multi-module project but i don't want to share all the sources if some one else is checking out this project, Is there a way to make custom build according to the need while checking out the projects from SVN , Some thing like some one would have privilege for Child Project A Sources not Child Project B and Some one else would have privilege for entire Project etc.,                  Thanks

Comment: I don't see an advantage of this. Just checkout the whole project and that's it. Use a multi-module build and you're fine.  What is the relationship to someone else is checking out the source? Does not matter. Can you describe in detail why you need to do this? What is the problem with checking out the whole project and building it ?

Comment: Some would be working with web and some would be working with utils , I need the one who is working with web should not make any changes or look on how and what things  are with the uitl,  their wiring etc., , So to segregate the utility and web modules have to do this with multi module projects , any idea?

Comment: To be simple i need the advantages of flat project layout in the deep  layout project.

Comment: What is the advantage? If you have a hierarchical layout you should have that be represented into the checked in project as well.